# DrRacket: put two objects into big-bang

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

How can i put two objects with its own coordinates

```
(define padle1 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "red"))
(define padle2 (rectangle 10 30 "solid" "red"))
(define (place-dot-at ... ) ...)
```

into bin-bang function

```
(big-bang ...
[to-draw place-dot-at])
```

Can i use list of padles

```
(define new-list (list padle1 padle2))
```

Comment: Please elaborate in more detail what you have already tried, what you are struggling with. Check for typos.

Comment: i'm trying to make a game a like space invaders

Answer (score 3):

`big-bang` stores only *one* piece of information, usually called the "world state." All the functions that work with `big-bang`, like your drawing function, tick handler, and so on, must accept that world state as a single parameter.

It's up to you to decide what to store in your world state. If you want to store two locations (one for each paddle), a list or struct is the way to go. For instance, here is how you might define a struct called `world` that can hold two positions at once.

```
; Create a type called `world` that holds two locations.
(define-struct world [paddle1 paddle2])

; Create a variable to store the initial state of the world.
(define initial-world (make-world (make-posn 0 100) (make-posn 300 100)))
```

When you write your drawing function, it must accept the entire world state at once:

```
(define (draw-game world)
   (place-image 
      paddle1
      (posn-x (world-paddle1 world))
      (posn-y (world-paddle1 world))
      (place-image 
         paddle2
         (posn-x (world-paddle2 world))
         (posn-y (world-paddle2 world))
         BACKGROUND)))
```

In your `big-bang`, treat the world state like any other kind of data:

```
(big-bang
  initial-world
  [to-draw draw-game])
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend making a `draw-paddle` function that draws a single paddle on top of an image `i`.

```
(define (draw-paddle p i)
   (overlay/xy (rectangle ...)  ; the paddle
               50 70            ; coordinates on paddle on screen
               i))              ; image of what's previously drawn
```

Then make a function that draws all paddles in a list on top of an image `i`.

```
(define (draw-paddles ps i)
   (cond
      [(empty? ps) i]           ; no more paddles to draw
      [else        (draw-paddles 
                        (rest ps)       ; draw the rest of the paddles on top
                        (draw-paddle (first p) i))])) ; of the first paddle
                                                      ; ontop of i
```

Then finally you can made:

```
 (define (on-draw state)
     (draw-paddles (list paddle1 paddle2) my-background))
```

If you don't have a background you can make one with `empty-image` or `rectangle`.